# Use of a DC power supply and an arbitrary wave generator in digital circuits

Tags: power-supply, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, awg

I am a communications and electronics engineering student from home because of obvious reasons, i´ve mannaged to acquire a regulated DC power supply an arbitrary wave generator and a mini oscilloscope this far to make a little home lab.

I took a class in basic digital circuits, multiplexers, decoders, counters, bcd to 7 segment, etc.

We simulated the circuits but i wish to repeat the Laboratory practices physically .

I understand that i can generate a clock signal with a 555 integrated circuit and all other chips powered by the DC power supply with common positive and negative nodes.

But it came to my mind that i can also generate a clock signal with the AWG, is there a way that i can skip the use of the 555 chip and use the AWG? if so, how would i connect it? positive to clock in and negative to common negative with the DC power supply?

Also the AWG has to channels, and it can generate DC signals, could I use one channel for DC power and the other for clock signal? how would you connect that?

Comment: Yes, but check your AWG can output sufficient current to achieve valid logic levels, especially if it is driving clock to multiple ICs.

Comment: Old and cheap and not-AWG generators may have three or more outputs. I'm just looking over at an ancient 'global specialties' right now and I see: CMOS, TTL, and 50 Ohms. That said, the fancy Fluke 294 I'm also looking at provides a settable peak compliance voltage of up to about 20 Vpp into a 50 Ohm load. (1 Watt.) It doesn't directly support CMOS or TTL output. So, Ricardo, you may need to learn how to ***adapt*** the output you have to the output you need -- by learning some basic, useful discrete circuit topologies.

Comment: Yes with the caveats in answers and comments. It's a good way to get your prototype running faster (which is why you can buy AWGs). (But it won't make a good DC power supply). Later you'll need the 555 or crystal oscillator as you get closer to finalising the design for production.

Answer (score 3):

The waveform generator can make a variety of shapes: sine, triangle, sawtooth, square, or one of your own design (that's the "arbitrary" part.) It can certainly replace a 555 as a clock source.

To do that, your generator should have a setting to make logic pulses, that is square-waves that swing from 0 to some + logic voltage (e.g., 5V or 3.3V). Try this out by connecting your scope to the AWG, and experiment with the settings to get the desired waveform.

Finally, the AWG can in theory generate DC, but it's not a good idea to use it that way as a power supply as you risk damaging it. Your power supply is much cheaper and easier to fix or replace, and is much more robust if you make a mistake. Also note that the signal gen has an output impedance of 50 ohms, so the delivered DC isn't going to be what you expect because of the IR drop in that impedance.

In any event, the best policy with an AWG is to first set up and check it with a scope to see if it's doing what you expect, then connect it to your system. Assuming you have your signals right, connect the ground of the generator to your system ground, and signal to signal.

Similar things come up with your power supply. Set it up, and check it first before you connect it. You can measure it with a scope, but you may find it handier to use a multimeter.

Comment: Note that many (most?) AWGs are calibrated for a load of 50 ohms. They have a source impedance of 50 ohms, so if your load is high-impedance, you will get twice what the AWG display says. Always verify the output with a scope.